# Notice if searchbar is focused then set state true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a SearchBar on the top of my screen.
Now, when i focus the searchbar (click on it once) the pointer is on the searchbar, and i can start typing.
Is there a way, to save this as a usestate?.
So if the focus (pointer) is on the searchbar and i can start typing, its true, else its false?
This is my searchbar:

```
  <View>
        <SearchBar
            platform={Platform.OS}
            placeholder="Start searching"
            value={stringToSearch}
            onChangeText={text => {
                setStringToSearch(text)
    
            }}
        />
    </View>
```

Depending on this state, (if its true) I want to display the last searches, otherwise something else.

Is there a way to store this state of the searchbar? (Focused, ready to type = true, else false)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onFocus` and `onBlur` to achieve this. You just need to pass `onFocus` and `onBlur` to the `<input/>` your `SearchBar` is wrapping.

```
        const [isSearchbarFocused, setSearchbarFocused] = useState(false)

        <SearchBar
            platform={Platform.OS}
            placeholder="Start searching"
            value={stringToSearch}
            isFocused={isSearchbarFocused}
            onFocus={() => {
             setSearchbarFocused(true)
            }}
            onChangeText={text => {
                setStringToSearch(text)
            }}
            onBlur={() => {
             setSearchbarFocused(false)
            }}
        />
```